# This Oracle trigger has problems

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER SumUpdate AFTER INSERT ON stavkaotpremnice FOR EACH ROW 
declare pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
UPDATE otpremnica a
  set a.ukupno= 
    (SELECT SUM(ukupno) 
       FROM stavkaotpremnice
      WHERE brojotpremnice =: new.brojotpremnice)
 WHERE a.brojotpremnice = :new.brojotpremnice;
 commit;
 end;
```

This trigger is to sum values of a column called "ukupno" in table stavakaotpremnice then store it in another table otpremnica in a column also called "ukupno".
The trigger check if the id(brojotpremnice) is the same and make the sum.
Brojotpremnice is a foreign key from table otpremnica.
Does anyone know why it is totally ignoring the first entry?
If i put rows in stavkaotpremnica i just count the first entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem can be solved via incremental addition as follows:

```
UPDATE otpremnica a
  set a.ukupno = a.ukupno + :new.ukupno
 WHERE a.brojotpremnice = :new.brojotpremnice;
```

Also, please read about `pragma autonomous_transaction`. Why it is used? Intentional? If you have no idea, read it. (It separates the transaction)

Comment: i been literally one week in this trigger man, thank u so much, worked fine.
And yes i took pragma part off.
Thanks u so much.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it resolved your issue.